# Redux - Previous values for props/state showing briefly before new values loaded

Tags: react-redux

I am setting up my React project with Redux for the first time, and am running into an issue.

I have a basic container, mapStateToProps, action creator, and reducer in place, but I'm having this issue where when I load a certain page, the previous prop values are getting loaded to the page before the correct values are fetched. It makes sense that this is happening, but I was wondering if there was a way to get around this so that upon loading this component / container that the values would get cleared. (Or if it'd just be better to use React state instead of Redux state for this specific use case? The rest of the pages make sense to use Redux, but this is the only case where this becomes an issue)

Say I have a page that shows some state of some item: somePage.com/items/

The component and container are set up like this (skeletal for the sake of example):

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component<......> {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       props.dispatch(fetchItemDetail(params));
   }
   render() {
       // use the stuff in props to display item's info
   }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
   return {
      someItemDetail: state.someItemDetail.X;
      someOtherInfo: state.someDetail.Y;
   }
} 

export const ItemDetailContainer = connect(mapStateToProps)(SomeComponent)
```

The action creator involves calling an API and returning the payload, and the reducer is just a standard reducer that sticks the result of the API call into the state.

Basically, this "works", but if I navigate from going into SomeComponent with a parameter for ItemX, and click a link to go to SomeComponent for ItemY, ItemX's information will show until the call to fetch ItemY's info completes, then ItemY's info will appear.

What's the recommended approach for handling this issue? It looks like I can't just clear the props upon construction because they are readonly. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-answer:

I got something to work. Basically, I ended up just creating an action creator, `clearItemDetail` w/ `CLEAR_ITEM_DETAIL` type. When the reducer sees actions with CLEAR_ITEM_DETAIL, they would then "clear" that part of the state. (I had multiple things to clear, so my actions and reducers were a little more complicated than this though.)

I dispatched the `clearItemDetail()` action creator inside the `componentWillUnmount()` lifecycle method of the component, and it seems to be working now.

Not sure if this is the best route though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like fetchItemDetail is an asynchronous call. That being so, write a reducer for fetchItemDetail to clear ItemY's data. The reducer can coexist with the middleware to handle the asynchronous call.

```
case FETCH_ITEM_DETAIL:
    return Object.assign({}, state, {ItemY: null});
    break;
```

You can handle the null value in ItemY in your component to not show any data. Then, upon completion of the asynchronous call, assign the returned value (this sounds like it's already done as the ItemY data does appear when the call is complete):

```
case FETCH_ITEM_COMPLETE:
    return Object.assign({}, state, {ItemY: [your item y data]});
    break;
```